# Angular Material Sidenav toggle animation doesn't hide/display on button toggle

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to using Angular Material components. I tried to add a `Sidenav`to my existing personal project. It displays the content contained in both `<mat-sidenav>` and `<mat-sidenav-content>`
However, for some reason, the toggle animation doesn't seem to work. I tried on 3 different browsers (Edge, Firefox, Chrome) private/incognito and non-private/non-incognito mode but toggle animation doesn't work.

I am not sure if it's because the `<mat-sidenav-container>` is contained in an enclosing parent div. I have the assumption that it should not affect the behavior of `<mat-sidenav-container>`

In the image below, **Settings** tab is active.
Problem:

1. **Sidenav** area still displays on load when it shouldn't (`opened=false` is default value in the `SettingsComponent`)
2. **Toggle Opened** button has no effect and doesn't hide/display the **Sidenav** area when you click on it.

[image]

**settings.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.component.css']
})
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  opened = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

**settings.component.html**

```
<p>settings works!</p>
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav [(opened)] = "opened">Sidenav</mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>Main
        <button (click)="opened=!opened">Toggle Opened</button>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="links" role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
          <a routerLink="/home/mystudents">My Students</a>
        </li>
        <li class="links" role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active">
          <a routerLink="gradingsheet">Grading Sheet</a>
        </li>
        <li class="links" role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active">
          <a [routerLink]="['mastersheet']">Master Sheet</a>
        </li>
        <li class="links" role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active">
          <a [routerLink]="['/home/sf2']">SF2-Learners Daily Attendance</a>
        </li>
        <li class="links" role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active">
          <a [routerLink]="['/home/sf9']">SF9-Report Cards</a>
        </li>
        <li class="links" role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active">
          <a [routerLink]="['/home/sf10']">SF10-Permanent Records</a>
        </li>
        <li class="links" role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active">
          <a [routerLink]="['usersmasterlist']">Users Masterlist</a>
        </li>
        <li class="links" role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active">
          <a [routerLink]="['settings']">Settings</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg col-lg-12">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MyStudentsComponent } from './my-students/mystudents.component';
import { MasterSheetComponent } from './master-sheet/mastersheet.component';
import { GradingSheetComponent } from './grading-sheet/gradingsheet.component';
import { UserComponent } from './master-sheet/user/user.component';
import { EditCredentialComponent } from './grading-sheet/edit-credential/edit-credential.component';
import { CredentialComponent } from './grading-sheet/credential/credential.component';
import { CredentialsService } from './grading-sheet/credentials.service';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { CanDeactivateGuard } from './grading-sheet/edit-credential/can-deactivate-guard.service';
import { ErrorPageComponent } from './error-page/error-page.component';
import { CredentialResolver } from './grading-sheet/credential/credential-resolver.service';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SF2Component } from './sf2/sf2.component';
import { SF9Component } from './sf9/sf9.component';
import { SF10Component } from './sf10/sf10.component';
import { UsermasterlistComponent } from './usermasterlist/usermasterlist.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from "@angular/material/form-field";
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { AddDialogComponent } from './dialogs/add/add-dialog.component';

import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MyStudentsComponent,
        MasterSheetComponent,
        GradingSheetComponent,
        UserComponent,
        EditCredentialComponent,
        CredentialComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
        ErrorPageComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        SF2Component,
        SF9Component,
        SF10Component,
        UsermasterlistComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AddDialogComponent,
        SettingsComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot({
            positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
        })
    ],
    providers: [CredentialsService, AuthService, AuthGuard, CanDeactivateGuard, CredentialResolver],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**home.component.html** contains the routerlinks of the different tabs
There's no error. The hide/slide animation on toggle just won't work.

Has anyone encountered anything similar to this? How did you resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is is normal that the MatSidenavModule is not listed in the imports of the AppModule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code. `Toggle Opened` closes/opens the sidenav.

Working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-sidenav-example-csv14t?file=app%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html

Make sure `import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';` has been added to `@NgModule`.

Follow the API: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the missing import of `MatSidenavModule` at `@NgModule` that was causing the issue. I can now proceed in developing.